# How to fix error: unknown type name ‘namespace’

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef UNO_ACTION_ 
#define UNO_ACTION_
namespace Uno
{
namespace Game
{
    class Game;
}
} // namespace

namespace Uno
{
namespace Action
{
using ::Uno::Game::Game;

class Action
{
public:
    virtual bool isDisposeable() = 0;
    virtual void takeAction(Game* game) = 0;
    virtual ~Action() {}
};

}
}
#endif
```

I compile these code on ubuntu 12.04 and it returns to set of error:

```
action.h:4:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
action.h:4:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
action.h:8:1: error: unknown type name ‘namespace’
action.h:8:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
```

How do I solve these errors?

Comment: Are you trying to mix C and C++ code?

Comment: Why C tagged ... ?code is completley c++

Comment: compile with `g++` rather than with `gcc`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to compile your C++ code with a C compiler. Try using `g++` instead of `gcc` and giving your file a C++ extension such as `.cpp` (rather than `.c`).

Comment: But the file is a `.h` file in this case.  This is probably why it broke.  I know `clang` will automatically detect a `.cpp` file and (essentially) run `clang++`, but this "trick" probably doesn't work if the coder isn't using `.hpp`.  (I haven't tested with `gcc`.)

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue with YCM and clang. Turns out, the missing flag was `"-x", "c++"`.

From the official clang [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html#cmdoption-x):

> -x <language> : Treat subsequent input files as having type language.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found this question but the solutions don't match mine completely, so I'm adding mine here.

In my case, I was including a header file in .cpp files and .c files.
The solution was to split off the namespace part of the header since that was obviously only needed in the .cpp files.