# XCode thinks C++ files are C when building for iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, compilation

I am working on a C++ project in XCode 5.1.1. The project compiles fine for OSX, but when I build for iOS I am hitting a problem. The compiler is producing errors that suggest it thinks some files are in C, and not in C++. The files in question all appear to be header-only files with no corresponding cpp file.

As background, the project is based on Cocos2d-x 3.0, and compiled for iOS fine a couple of weeks ago. Since then I added [jl_signals](https://github.com/jeffomatic/jl_signal) which makes use of [FastDelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible), which I know does some non-standard things that are beyond my understanding.

These are some of the errors I'm getting:

```
namespace fastdelegate {
```

...produces the errors:

```
[...]/jlsignal/FastDelegate.h:142:1: Unknown type name 'namespace'
[...]/jlsignal/FastDelegate.h:142:23: Expected ';' after top level declarator
```

Also, problems finding the standard library:

```
#include <new>
```

...produces the error

```
[...]]/jlsignal/ScopedAllocator.h:7:10: 'new' file not found
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602249/how-to-fix-error-unknown-type-name-namespace) stack overflow question suggests that the compiler is trying to build the project as c and not c++, which seems to fit the symptoms, but it seems strange that it is isolated only to this one particular library.

I am wondering if there is some build phase or XCode specific tickbox somewhere I have neglected. Thanks.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**: Some people have suggested that I rename the file from .m to .mm, but the file is a .h header file so I can't follow this advice. All the other C++ files in the project are .cpp files, and the project has definitely been compiling successfully as C++ until I added this library.

**EDIT 2**: OK I have got it working. It turns out that the advice about .m vs .mm was right after all. It all came down to the fact that in Cocos2d-x the ios build has a separate main file from the mac build, which was called main.m. I changed it to main.mm and all was well. The entire project is in c++ so the compiler was figuring it out somehow, but something was getting tripped up here.

Comment: rename .m file to .mm

Comment: Select the file in the file list, open the file properties panel.  There is a section there where you can specify the type of the file.

Comment: @HotLicks - Hi. I have tried setting the type to "C++ Header" but with no effect. Also, the project already has many header-only files in it that compile as c++ already, even though their "type" is set to default "C header"

Comment: I'll bet the problem is that you're importing that .h file into something other than a C++ .mm or .cpp file.  If you do that you need to add #if conditional logic to skip around C++-only statements.

Comment: Thanks. You got me looking in the right place.

Comment: Use `#ifdef __cplusplus` to test the compiler version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode activates the c++ compiler for any files named `filename.mm`. I'm guessing your file is named `filename.m`.

Comment: it's actually called FastDelegate.h, and is header-only (so no .m or .mm) All other files are .cpp, and the project is a C++ project.